# How to ensure that files are copied from my working directory into bin/Debug rsp. bin/Release?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

I have various files in my Visual Studio Solutions that have to be copied to the bin/Debug folder if I change it.

I tried to set `Copy to Output Directory - Copy always` but it doesnt work. So how can i make sure that when building these files are copied to bin/debug?

Here a screenshot from one example:
[image]

Comment: Is your build succeeding? Changing the Copy to Output Directory property on a file should work. Note that it will copy to bin/Debug if you're in Debug mode, and bin/Release if you're in Release mode.

Comment: @AndyC the build is working, but the files aren't copied. And yes Debug/Release I know

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure the build action for the files are marked as [content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx), otherwise they will not be copied while building.

> Content - The file is not compiled, but is included in the
>   Content output group. For example,
>   this setting is the default value for
>   an .htm or other kind of Web file.

Comment: I did that. I added a screenshot in my question with one example. I tried, but this file isn't copied into bin/Debug.

Comment: Ok my fault. Setting to content worked, I didn't saw that the files are copied with their folders!

Comment: If you want just a file to be copied, without the directories, maybe you could use post-build action on the project properties.

Comment: @Johnny5 Thanks but now I know that it is copied with the directories.That's also ok.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Debug profile? The build section of your properties has an output path which is set to bin/debug if you are using this profile.

Comment: Yes I know but not all files are copied.

Comment: diffrent files... DLL, EXE and XML. I added a screenshot!